# Embedding version control within App

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, svn

I am building an application to learn cocoa, basically its a notes keeping app. But i wanted to build a functionality where i can see what happen to the document over time, i think using subversion/version control software can help me in this task. But how i can embed it within an app?

Answer (score 2):

Git might be a better choice and there is a partial Objective-C implementation at http://github.com/schacon/objective-git.

Answer (score 0):

The subversion book has [section](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.developer) on this topic.

Comment: I have seen it but i think it require you to have it on the system, i wanted it like within my app bundle, not in the system. Though subversion is installed in os x but i still dont wanted to use that thing. I am looking for some simple/lightweight solution which i can put directory in my app. There is another problem in using it, it provide you c wrapper but not a objC wrapper (at-least i have google it and have not found any). Though i can use C without any problem but it stil bugs me!

Comment: I see what you meant, too bad about the objC wrapper. If you want to use it as part of your app, you can get the subversion lib that you need and do static compile and link your code against it. So you do not have to rely whether the platform has subversion or not, although this will be extra work for you :(

Comment: hmm, i think that can be considered.